# C [x ... y] ranged assignment

Tags: c, arrays

I came across some code today which used syntax that in my years of doing C programming I've never seen before.

MWE:

```
#include<stdio.h>

char *example_array[] = {
    [0 ... 5] = "hello world",
    [6 ... 10] = "goodbye world"
};

int main(void) {
    printf("%s, %s.\n", example_array[3], example_array[7]);
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
hello world, goodbye world.
```

It's pretty clear what's going on here in a static context, but I'm curious if this can be used as a convenient shortcut in non-static shortcuts, such as assignments in a loop.  Of course, it wouldn't give any performance boost that `-funroll-loops` couldn't, but it might make for cleaner code in, say, matrix row assignments or otherwise.

`clang` and `gcc` give no warnings by default when using this syntax, but I've never seen it documented anywhere.  Is this some kind of extension, or is it standard C syntax?

Comment: with clang `-Wgnu-designator`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a GNU extension to designated initializers supported by both gcc and clang, which you can read about [in the gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html).  Note that this is only for initializers, not for assignments, which are very different things, despite both using the `=` symbol.

Comment: This is incorrect, it is part of the C standard since C99.

Comment: @DietrichEpp No, the C standard does not allow ranges in designated initializers

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't notice that part. Might be a good idea to make it clear what extension you are talking about, then.

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't realize this was in any spec because I didn't know what to call it - does it have an official name?