# C Arrays Designated Initializer in C#

Tags: c#

Using an ellipses, `...`, as was asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51904543/c-x-y-ranged-assignment), allows you to initialize many indices of a **C** array to the same value.

Obviously this is a very useful shorthand for having all, or specific indices, of an array be a certain value, as the code required to do so is extremely short.

Is there a similar method of doing that in **C#**?

Let's say that I have a `char` array named `charArray` whose length is 50.  If I wanted to have all indices to be `'h'`, I would have to do something like this, to my knowledge:

```
char[] charArray = new char[50];
for(int i = 0; i < charArray.Length; i++)
    charArray[i] = 'h';
```

Can I shorten this code segment any further?

If so, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308604/initializing-a-c-sharp-array-with-multiple-copies-of-the-same-element

Comment: Initializing array in for loop will be the most performant way in c#

Comment: @MineR noted.  I edited the loop and `charArray` should be assigned values now.